# Set DateTimePicker to 12/31/[THIS YEAR]

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, datetimepicker

I want to display in my **DatetimePicker** always the **End of the year**.

For example this year **12/31/2016**.

Then if its 01/01/2017 today then the **DateTimePicker** will display 2017 **End of the Year** which its **12/31/2017**.

How can I **Set/Code** this to **DateTimePicker**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it for the current year:

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31)
```

Comment: Thank you sir :) I wish i could buy you a coffee someday :D